# How can I run Jenkins job via eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, eclipse-plugin

I don't use maven, I use ant (if it related...)
Should I create a new plugin?
Is there any exist one?

I tried to look for instruction but all related to maven.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try this [plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hudsonjenkins-mylyn-builds-connector) which adds a view to Eclipse and allows you to monitor and trigger build jobs on Jenkins or Hudson.

Comment: It doesn't related to CI.
The Jenkins job build new release.

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's a plugin to interact with Jenkins.